# Подключение шрифта без указания толщины

Tags: css, шрифты

Имеется шрифт с несколькими видами толщины:
Museo Sans Cyrl 100
Museo Sans Cyrl 500
Museo Sans Cyrl 900

Подключаю следующим образом, но не работает:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl";
    src: url("../fonts/Museo Sans Cyrl 100.ttf") format(truetype);
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl";
    src: url("../fonts/Museo Sans Cyrl 500.ttf") format(truetype);
    font-weight: 500;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl";
    src: url("../fonts/Museo Sans Cyrl 900.ttf") format(truetype);
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Работает только тогда, когда каждый отдельно пропишу с указанием толщины:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl 900";
    src: url("../fonts/Museo Sans Cyrl 900.ttf") format(truetype);
    font-weight: 900;
} ...
```

Может, я чего-то не знаю о подключении?

Comment: Не понятно в чем проблема. Первый листинг - правильный, второй нет. Если хотите, чтобы какая-то жирность была по умолчанию задайте ее родителю или добавьте шрифт на 400(т е normal). А то получается у вас нормальная жирность не добавлена, тогда конечно каждую прописывать придется.

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, должен быть обязательно шрифт с толщиной 400, который будет задавать толщину по умолчанию?

Answer (score 2):

Плохая практика плодить разные имена одного того же шрифта, еще и прописывать им разные жирности. Такой код плохо поддерживается. Новый разработчик должен знать все ваши "придуманные" названия несуществующих шрифтов, и при добавлении нового начертания, или изменении шрифта может может появиться много работы. Если шрифт один, он должен быть один и у него может быть несколько начертаний.

Вообще не прописывать жирность не получится, и совершенно не ясно зачем это делать. По умолчанию в браузере, в нормализе или в резет жирность всегда будет прописана и как правило это - 400 т.е. `normal`. Вы этот шрифт не добавляете, и соответственно по умолчанию вы обращаетесь к этому шрифту с таким начертанием, а его нет. Либо добавьте по умолчанию жирность 500, либо добавьте этот шрифт с жирностью 400.

Вот пример подключения в вашем случае.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot');
  src: url('MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff2') format('woff2'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff') format('woff'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-100.ttf') format('truetype'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-100.svg#MuseoSansCyrl-100') format('svg'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot');
  src: url('MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff2') format('woff2'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff') format('woff'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-500.ttf') format('truetype'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-500.svg#MuseoSansCyrl-100') format('svg'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot');
  src: url('MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff2') format('woff2'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff') format('woff'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-900.ttf') format('truetype'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-900.svg#MuseoSansCyrl-100') format('svg'), url('MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
}

i {
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

---

И уберите пробелы в именах файлов.

Comment: К сожалению, не прокатывает так... Шрифты остаются стандартными

Comment: Без рабочего примера сложно догадаться что именно не так

Comment: Где именно перекрывается? Смотрели ли вы в инспекторе, что там? Как вызываете шрифты? Где смотрите, какой браузер? Подключили ли что-то кроме ttf?

Comment: В хроме смотрю. В инспекторе стоит активным подключенный шрифт, но очевидно, что он неподключен. Подключал ttf, woff, woff2

Comment: @kizoso Поздравляю от души с достижением нового уровня - 5000!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT (*^‿^*) Спасибо!

Comment: @kizoso заходите к нам на огонек, в теплую компанию, когда будет время и желание У нас интересно https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно такая же проблема с этим же шрифтом. Все испробовал, попробовал для интереса твой способ с указанием толщины шрифта в названии, и заработало.

```
  @font-face {
        font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl 500';
        src: url('Museo_Sans_Cyrillic/MuseoSansCyrl_500.otf') format('otf');
        font-weight: 500;
    .nav {
        font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl 500';
```

Comment: "твой способ" - извините, а чей? Здесь вопрос и ещё три ответа.

Comment: Способ автора имелся в виду.

Comment: upd. Разобрался в таком странном поведении. Указанное свойство font-family использовало установленный в системе шрифт, а не подгружаемый при помощи font-face. Добавил ссылки на все остальные форматы шрифтов, и стало грузить, но возникла следующая проблема - хоть шрифт и с поддержкой кириллицы, в реальности применяется только к латинице и к цифрам. Пробовал два разных файла шрифта. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: upd upd. Столкнулся с этой же проблемой с другим шрифтом, и разобрался в конце концов. Хоть скачиваешь шрифт и кириллический, но когда конвертируешь другие форматы через fontsuirell, если в опциях отдельно не указать, что нужен кириллический, то новые форматы не будут таковыми. Наверное, это ошибка новичка такая, и все это и так знают, но вдруг кому будет полезно.

Answer (score 0):

У вас же разные файлы с шрифтами а пробуете прописать всех под одно имя

для каждого `Font-Family` дайте отдельное имя.

Например:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl twing";
    src: url("../fonts/Museo Sans Cyrl 100.ttf") format(truetype);
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl Regular";
    src: url("../fonts/Museo Sans Cyrl 500.ttf") format(truetype);
    font-weight: 500;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl Bold";
    src: url("../fonts/Museo Sans Cyrl 900.ttf") format(truetype);
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Нет! Это не правильное подключение, имя шрифта должно быть одно, а вот жирности разные

Comment: Вот покажите как надо - у меня 3 файла с разными `font-weight`, как по мне так создание для каждого отдельное имя оптимально.

Comment: Я хотел бы использовать одно название шрифта, а в стилях потом просто `font-weight` менять

Answer (score 0):

В общем, товарищи, такая дичь. Не знаю, чем это объяснимо, надеюсь, кто-нибудь объяснит, но работает у меня только следующим образом:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl";
    src: url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl100.ttf") format(truetype),
         url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl100.woff") format(woff),
         url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl100.woff2") format(woff2);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl";
    src: url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl500.ttf") format(truetype),
         url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl500.woff") format(woff),
         url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl500.woff2") format(woff2);
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl";
    src: url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl900.ttf") format(truetype),
         url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl900.woff") format(woff),
         url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl900.woff2") format(woff2);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}


h1 {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl 700";
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl 500";
}
```

Только когда толщина подписывается в конце названия.

Comment: Очень странно.. Может быть этот шрифт таким образом где-то уже подключен ранее

Comment: Не представляю, как такое может быть возможно, ведь проект с нуля

Comment: В приведённом примере ты используешь имена шрифтов, которые не создавал.